# Docker container respawns after killing

Tags: docker

I have rogues docker containers running on my system. I have tried to kill them but they seem to restart again.

I have tried to remove the restart option in the hostconfig.json of the container, with no luck.

I have even tried to clear all the images.

is there any way to force kill these containers?

Comment: Are you using docker-swarm? Could you add to your question more information about your setup?

Comment: Please be more precise: " I have tried to kill them" -> How? "they seem to restart again." -> What makes you think that? What command did you try?

Answer (score 6):

You may have started it as a service.  Check to see if that is the case by running:

`docker service ls`

If you see your service there you can delete it by doing

`docker service rm <service id>`

You could also `docker service inspect <service id>` to see more details about what the service is and why it is respawning.